# What is a standard calculation that takes O(log N) in Big O notations?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, big-o

I'm a computer science student and I have to write an analysis performed on different big O algorithms. To facilitate us our professor gave us a few methods to override to monitor the times of our implementations.

The first method is supposed to contain an implementation of the Big O algorithm analysed and the second one a standard 'control' line.

For example, **quadratic time**:

```
  public void method1(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        analyser();
      }
    }
  }
```

Control:

```
  public int method2(int n) {
    return n*n;
  }
```

Now for the **logarithmic** function:

```
  public void method1(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i*2) {
        analyser();
    }
  }


  @Override
  public int method2(int n) {
    return (int) Math.log(n);
  }
```

Unfortunately the second method is returning infinite values and I cannot understand why. There's any other simple calculation I could use instead of `Math.log(n)` to use as 'control' to compare the times of the two methods ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`method2` will return undefined for `n=0` because `log(0)` is by definition undefined. You can change this simply by asserting that `n` is greater than 0 in the method. If this assertion fails, the calls on the stack trace and / or stepping through in debug will help determine where `method2` is invoked with`n=0`.

Comment: Unfortunately does not help. There should exist another function that I can use in method2